# Can Not copy rsa key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, digital-ocean

When I try to run `ssh-copy-id` then I am getting following **error:**

```
abcd@hostOnDigitalOcean:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id xyz@targetHostIP
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/abcd/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host targetHostIP port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have tried `ssh-copy-id -i <path_of_id_rsa.pub> xyz@targetHostIP`
also but same error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about server configuration, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy it manually.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

`ssh` to `targetHostIP`

paste at the end at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`